# Site links in search snippets on Bing SERPs, how to influence which links to show?

Tags: seo, search-results, rich-snippets, bing

> [image: Bing result for a webpage shows additional four links]

See, there are links under a search result in BING SERP. Sometimes these links are pure nonsense and I'd like to select good relevant links to use on there.

But how do I influence Bing to show the links I picked?

UPDATE: I suspect that this is a new feature BING is testing on SERPs at the moment...

Answer (score 1):

Sitemap protocol is using an important feature called priority so depending on these values you can give more importance to an url than another. Also there's a concept called AdWords Ad Ranking Formula http://searchengineland.com/new-adwords-ad-ranking-formula-what-does-it-mean-174946

So depending on what the crawlers can see and is prioritized in sitemap and ranking says those links should be constructed. So IMHO you can try prioritize whatever you want but don't abuse of this feature as is designed to make certain content findable by the **user**.